# Twitter search api same Return result

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

Sometimes am getting **SAME return values** from twitter search api based on geo location even though the request parameters are different. Can any one help me to understand why this is happening...is that because of any cache issue from twitter??

Regards,
Navin